# Problems with saving to pdf file in Julia

Tags: julia

Good evening,

I have a problem with formatting in pdf file after converting it from .jl (Julia file).

For example, $ I_{1}, I_{2}, I_{3} $ [illustration the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEIsz.png)  is not shown
like a normal text. It is shown as the set of symbols, including $, _ , { , }. The headers are also shifted in pdf but in jl (Julia file) they are shown correctly.

How to fix this?

Kind regards,

Ilya

Comment: How did you convert the .jl file to .pdf?

Comment: I converted .jl to .pdf in juliabox.com. I downloaded as PDF via Latex(.pdf)